# Javascript LinkedIn API Sign In Issues

Tags: javascript, api, authentication, linkedin-api

I am trying to create a form that grabs values from the user's LinkedIn profile in order to make it easier to sign on. I am having trouble grabbing some of the fields.

When I try to auto populate my form I have no issues grabbing First Name, Last Name, LinkedIn ID, and Headline. When I try to grab other fields like location, previous jobs, and industry and error appears on the page (ie. "Error: industry is not defined"). Note: this application has full profile privileges. I have attached snippets of my code and the results in the links below. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Working Code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYyaH.png

Non Working Code (added industry field):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ounnW.png

Comment: Here are the outputs as well:
Working Output:
http://i.imgur.com/RKK8Xyq.png

Non Working Output:
http://i.imgur.com/MzzQHV3.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that is working

```
 <script type="IN/Login"> 
            <input type="text" value="<?js= firstName ?>" />
    <input type="text" value="<?js= id ?>" />

        </script>
```

In below script use `ID` that is available from above script

```
    <script type="IN/MemberData"
    data-ids="`here_put_the_ID`"
    data-fields="firstName,lastName,industry">
<ul>
<?js for (var member in $("*")) { ?>
    <li><?js= $(member).firstName ?> <?js= $(member).lastName ?> 
    Industry : <?js= $(member).industry ?></li>
<?js } ?>
</ul>
</script>
```

the second way is to get information is

```
   function callmeOnLoad(){ 
        IN.API.Profile("me")
        .fields("id", "firstName", "lastName", "pictureUrl", "publicProfileUrl","industry")
        .result(function(result, metadata) {
          setConnections(result.values, metadata);
        });

    }   
    function setConnections(connections) {

        for (id in connections) {
            console.log(connections[id].firstName+":"+connections[id].industry)
        }
    }
```

Comment: How would I be able to pass the id from above through data-ids based off of the above value. I can input a static id but I want it to vary based off of the user

Comment: yes how to set that value dynamically is one question...for that can you use the second way that I provided.? it will give industry dynamically for each profile